# Can't find the log4j2 configuration file

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I have a Java project in Eclipse Kepler and I'm trying to set up log4j. I've added it to the project using the following in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the following in my log4j config file which is named log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log4j2.xml is located in src/main/resources which I've added to the Java Build Path Source tab in Eclipse. When I launch the project, I'm able to use the logger. But, if I rename the config file to loggerconfig-dev.xml and add this to the VM arugments in Eclipse:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=loggerconfig-dev.xml
```

I get an error saying "No log4j2 configuration file found...". How do I get it to see the configuration file with the new name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*Configuring Log4j 2 - Apache Log4j 2*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

> Log4j will inspect the "**`log4j2.configurationFile`**" system property

So, you need to change to:

```
-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=loggerconfig-dev.xml
```

See also:

- [System Properties - Configuring Log4j 2 - Apache Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)

Answer (score -1):

For Future googlers, according to [Apache documents](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/configuration.html), the default file name is `log4j2-test.xml`. For more information and other default names, visit the aforementioned link.